# What is the difference between 自由に and 自由で?

Tags: grammar

自由に歩けなくても...   自由で歩けなくても..  can anyone differentiate this

Comment: Did you actually see/hear 「自由**で**歩けなくても」 someplace?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say "unable to walk freely", 自由に歩けない is the only correct option. 自由に is the adverbial form of 自由.

自由で is the te-form of 自由だ, so it's used to connect two adjectives or clauses. The first part often works as the reason/cause of the second part (see [te-form for reason](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html)). Technically speaking, 自由で歩けない means "to be free and (thus) unable to walk", but this makes little sense.

Comment: In this case, couldn't one think of で as a particle instead of as the -te form of the copula (as in バスで for instance)?

Comment: @Chewie No. It may sound possible to use 自由で to mean "at one's discretion" or something, but I cannot fund such an example on the net.